# split an array with object to 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have an array with multiple objects. I'd like to split this array to multiple arrays. The criteria to split is the item `continent`.

```
MyArray = [{continent:"europe", fruit:"orange", value:2},
           {continent:"asia", fruit:"banana", value:2},
           {continent:"europe", fruit:"apple", value:2},
           {continent:"asia", fruit:"apple", value:5}
          ];
```

Output:

```
[
 [{continent:"europe", fruit:"orange", value:2},
  {continent:"europe", fruit:"apple" value:2}
 ], [
  {continent:"asia", fruit:"banana", value:2},
  {continent:"asia", fruit:"apple" value:5}]
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could search for the array with the same continent and update this array or push a new array with the actual object.

```js
var array = [{ continent: "europe", fruit: "orange", value: 2 }, { continent: "asia", fruit: "banana", value: 2 }, { continent: "europe", fruit: "apple", value: 2 }, { continent: "asia", fruit: "apple", value: 5 }],
    grouped = array.reduce(function (r, o) {
        var group = r.find(([{ continent }]) => continent === o.continent)
        if (group) {
            group.push(o);
        } else {
            r.push([o]);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the continent and use `filter` to get the matched elements

```js
var MyArray = [{
  continent: "europe",
  fruit: "orange",
  value: 2
}, {
  continent: "asia",
  fruit: "banana",
  value: 2
}, {
  continent: "europe",
  fruit: "apple",
  value: 2
}, {
  continent: "asia",
  fruit: "apple",
  value: 5
}];
var getAllContinents = [];
 // getting the unique continent name
MyArray.forEach(function(item) {
  // if the continent  name is not present then push it in the array
  if (getAllContinents.indexOf(item.continent) === -1) {
    getAllContinents.push(item.continent)
  }
})
var modifiedArray = [];
//iterate over the continent array and find the matched elements where 
// continent name is same
getAllContinents.forEach(function(item) {
  modifiedArray.push(MyArray.filter(function(cont) {
    return cont.continent === item
  }))
})
console.log(modifiedArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also create an object with keys having values of specified property. This will allow you to access the desired array very easily.

You may use:

- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [`Arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

**Example:**

```js
let data = [{continent:"europe", fruit:"orange", value:2},      
            {continent:"asia", fruit:"banana", value:2},
            {continent:"europe", fruit:"apple", value:2},
            {continent:"asia", fruit:"apple", value:5}];

let result = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  acc[obj.continent] = acc[obj.continent] || [];
  acc[obj.continent].push(obj);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```